# Auto Assignment in BMC Remedy ITSM

Tags: variable-assignment, auto, remedy

I am looking for a solution to assign incidents assigned to my group to automatically get assigned to another group without any manual intervention. The auto assignment should be based on the value in Summary field.
I have tried manual assignment but looking for automated solution.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic assignment is setup in the Application Administration Console and is documented here: https://docs.bmc.com/docs/itsm2002/configuring-assignments-909628039.html

If this doesn't provide the capabilities that you need, then you can create a new filter which can run on update, looking for your group/summary criteria and then set the new group. https://docs.bmc.com/docs/ars2002/filters-909637117.html